# Sample size required to hit at least a constant fraction of a set.

Tags: probability-theory, sampling, distribution-tails

I have been trying to figure out the following problem for quite some time but have not succedded. May be I am missing something very obvious.

Let $M$ be and integer and define $[M] = \{1,\cdots,M\}$. Suppose $S\subseteq M$ with $\vert S\vert = \beta M$, for some $0< \beta <1$. Let $Y$ be a random sample of size $t$, where the sampling is done **without replacement**, meaning for a fixed  subset $P$ of $[M]$ of size $t$, $Pr[Y=P] = \frac{1}{\binom{M}{t}}$.

I want to show that for some constant $c<1$ $Pr[\vert Y\cap S\vert \geq c\vert S\vert] \geq \frac{1}{2}$, so that $Y$ contains a constant fraction of points of $S$, with constant probability. (For eaxample if we take, say $2\beta M$ points from $[M]$, the this sample will contain a constant fraction of $S$.) The main point I want to investigate whether the ratio $\frac{t}{\vert S\vert}$ is a constant. Another way to ask the question is what is the sample size required to cover at least a constant fraction of $S$ and whether this size grows linearly with $\vert S\vert$.

My first approach is to directly bound the probability. But before we relax the problem and assume indeed $t = \gamma\beta M$, for some constant $\gamma$ and that we are interested in the event $\vert Y\cap S\vert = c\vert S\vert$. As there are $\binom{\gamma\beta M}{c\beta M}$ possible subset of $Y$ of size $c\beta M$, the required probability is $\frac{\binom{\gamma\beta M}{c\beta M}}{\binom{M}{\gamma\beta M}}$ (assume for simplicity that all the parameters are integers), but I have not been able to simplify the expression, to show that $\gamma$ is indeed a constant, possibly depends on $c$.

My second approach relies on a general result of [Hoeffding](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Wassily_Hoeffding) (see Theorem 4 of  [Probability Inequalities for Sums of Bounded Random Variables](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2282952)), which roughly says that Chernoff type results also hold for sampling without replacement, if it holds for sampling with replacement. It is enough to take a uniform and independent sample $X$ of size $t$, where sampling is done with replacement and analyze the corresponding probability.

Now the issue with this approach is $\mathbb{E}[\vert X\cap S\vert] = \beta t$ and applying Chernoff type bound would imply that most of sample will belong to $S$, (meaning $\vert X\cap S\vert \geq c\vert X\vert$), not that most of the $S$ will belong to $X$ (meaning $\vert X\cap S\vert \geq c\vert S\vert$). I am kind of stuck here. At this point I am not quite sure if $\frac{\binom{\gamma\beta M}{c\beta M}}{\binom{M}{\gamma\beta M}}$ is the correct expression for the desired probability in the first case. My intuition is that, in the second case where $\beta$ is large, each sample will likely to be in $S$, so we need only constant time larger sample to cover at least a constant fraction of $S$. So far I have not been able to prove this.

Thanks

This question is closely related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198700/probability-that-a-random-samplewithout-replacement-contains-a-fixed-subset-of) .

Edit: I think the first approach works. I have incorrectly stated that the probability is $\frac{\binom{\gamma\beta M}{c\beta M}}{\binom{M}{\gamma\beta M}}$. In fact $\vert Y\cap S\vert$ is a **hypergeometric** random variable. Standard concentration inequality shows that $t=\frac{M}{2}$ works. In this case with high probability $\vert Y\cap S\vert \geq \frac{1}{4}\beta M$ and $\frac{t}{\vert S\vert} = \frac{1}{2\beta}$, a constant.